# Buildfire: buildfire.geo.getCurrentPosition is not working on mobile app(both android and ios) and PWA

Tags: buildfire

I have a page where I need to get the current location of the user base on the current location of the device, I have used the "buildfire.geo.getCurrentPosition", it is working on the localhost development but during publish it doesn't working.

```
buildfire.geo.getCurrentPosition(null, (err, position) => {
  if(err)
    console.log(err);
  else {
    let currentLoc = this.state.currentLoc;
    currentLoc['coordinates'] = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
    this.setState({currentLoc});
  }
});
```

[Working on localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qn7F.png)

[But not on the app control panel upon updating the plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B98gb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your plugin that is checking for the location has the appropriate feature specified in the [plugin.json](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-Fill-in-%22plugin.json%22-File) file.

Here's a sample plugin.json example, that includes that feature.

```
{
  "author":"Jane Doe"
  ,"pluginName":"Sample Plugin "
  ,"pluginDescription":"This is an example"
  ,"supportEmail":"support@buildfire.com"
  ,"control":{
    "content":{
      "enabled":true
    }
    , "design":{
      "enabled":true
    }
    , "settings":{
      "enabled":false
    }
  },
  "features" : [{"name" : "GEO"}],
  "languages" : ["en"],
}
```

Please note that adding a new feature to the plugin.json requires a hard build of your app, so you won't see the changes immediately.

Comment: I have added the feature to the plugin.json file. But still it is not working.

Comment: Do I need to serve the url as https and not http?
You only have https working example on your documentation.

https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/BuildFire-Geo-Location-(GPS)-Feature

Comment: This is the error from the control panel buildfire: 
[Deprecation] getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.

Comment: @ShawDonayre When you say it isn't working, can you clarify where it isn't working? Is this in the live app, or is this from your control panel? If it's your control panel then yes, it needs to be over HTTPS. Also, just to clarify what URL are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is in the control panel. Thanks. Clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the feature to the plugin.json file.

```
    {
  "author": "Sio Donayre"
  ,"pluginName": "Coupon Plugin"
  ,"pluginDescription": "Simple Discount Coupon Plugin"
  ,"supportEmail": "sio.donayre@go-va.com.au"
  ,"control": {
    "content": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  , "design": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  , "settings": {
      "enabled": false
    }
  }
  ,"widget": {},
  "features" : [
    {
      "name": "GEO"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Calendar"
    }
  ],
  "languages" : ["en"]
}
```